# Stop registration form from sending mails

Tags: emails

I want to stop the registration form from sending "email activated" email to users, is there a way to stop them?

Comment: Sorry about that, there is a check box in the account settings -> mail section -> account activation that says "notify users" just un tick that and we are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend, a search for "drupal 7 user registration email settings" produced:

- [User: access and management settings](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/user)

configure user registration, user email, and user picture settings on the Account settings page:

Administer > Configuration > People > Account settings) in Drupal 7, and (Administer > Settings > User) in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox in the *Account settings ->Mail section -> Account activation* that says "*Notify users*" just untick that and we are good to go.

To stop all e-mails, see: [How can I stop Drupal from sending e-mails of any kind?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/38255/1908)

Answer (score 0):

In drupal7 you need to go Administer > Configuration > People > Account settings to stop sending emails.