# How to make sure no emails go out after importing users?

Tags: users, migrations, emails

I'm creating a new Drupal site and importing users from our existing website. I want to make sure users don't receive any email notifications of any kind from our new website during this process. What things should I check to ensure this?

I am using Drupal 7.54.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off user mail on registration in account settings.

/admin/config/people/accounts

or if you'd like to see what is being sent by the system, but not have it go out to your users checkout the [MailLog](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) module. We use it to test email functionality during development. It has a checkbox to turn off all mail going out from your Drupal site.

Comment: Also see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38255/how-can-i-stop-drupal-from-sending-e-mails-of-any-kind for a bunch of other suggestions

Comment: I don't see the setting but this is all I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Development Environment](https://www.drupal.org/project/development_environment) module for this. Some more details about it (from the project page):

> When developing Drupal sites, we are often working in a development environment in which we want behaviors different than we would like on a production environment. An example of this is sending emails - it's often preferable to not send emails from a development environment, as they can end up in our client's email boxes. This is particularly true when there is a production (live) version of the site on the web, as users may receive emails from your development environment, which will be both confusing, and any links to the site within the emails will be unusable by anyone without access to that development environment.
>
> This module aims to provide various settings which are specific to development environments only.

<sup>Disclosure: I developed this module.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Reroute Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/reroute_email) module. From its project page:

> This module intercepts all outgoing emails from a Drupal site and reroutes them to a predefined configurable email address.
>
> This is useful in case where you do not want email sent from a Drupal site to reach the users. For example, if you copy a live site to a test site for the purpose of development, and you do not want any email sent to real users of the original site. Or you want to check the emails sent for uniform formatting, footers, ...etc.